# Error in onLoad()

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting error in following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="text/javascript">
function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height= (newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (newwidth) + "px";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"  id="iframe1" onLoad="autoResize(this);"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

I have checked all the quotes but didnt find anything wrong there.
Error: Object Expected

Comment: what about the `autoResize` code?

Comment: Seems to work fine here, it loads in Chrome and Firefox without issue.

Comment: Can you supply us with your autoResize code?

Comment: @  Stefan Ray .. pasted

Comment: Shouldn't be `autoResize(this.id)`?

Comment: sdespont .. yes this is but after that it is giving "Access denied" error...

Comment: `if(document.getElementById)` <-- That line looks strange to me. Did you mean to write `if(document.getElementById(id))`? Also, if that check happens to fail, you'll get `undefined` for `newheight` and `newwidth`, which will cause strange behaviors when they're used later in your function. It looks like the entire function should live inside that if-block.